# how can I write a if condition to break out of for loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, break

```
    for method,proprties,body in message:

        logger.info(proprties)
        logger.info(method)
        logger.info(body)

        self.channel.basic_ack(proprties.timestamp)
        k=proprties.timestamp
        logger.info(k)
#k = 1463761209429 
#k = 1463761194158  
#k = 1463756480546
```

I want to come out of this for loop if k contains 1463761209, I don't care about the last three digits just match me the first 10 digit and come out.

```
# Escape out of the loop 
        if k == ??:
            break
```

I want to write a if condition to break out of loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try converting k to a string and check sub string using `in` operator.

```
#for-loop
    if '1463761209' in str(k):
        break
```

That is only if performance is not a big issue!

Answer (score 3):

```
if str(k).startswith("1463761209"):
    break
```